# Card and Deck classes C++

Tags: c++

I am a very novice programmer and my assignment to create a Card and Deck class is a little bit over my head...I just need a little push in the right direction because I really have no clue what I am doing.

My Card header file:

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Card
{
public:
    static const char SPADES = 'S';
    static const char CLUBS = 'C';
    static const char HEARTS = 'H';
    static const char DIAMONDS = 'D';

    Card();
    Card(int v, char s);

    const string toString();
    const int compareCard(const Card c);

private:
    int value;
    char suit;
};
#endif
```

My Card implementation file:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Card::Card(int v, char s)
{
    if (v < 1 || v > 13)
    { 
            cerr << "Invalid Card value";
    }
    else
    {
        value = v;
    }

    if ((s != SPADES) && (s != HEARTS) && (s != DIAMONDS) && (s != CLUBS))
    {
        cerr << "Invalid Suit name";
    }
    else
    {
        suit = s;
    }
}

const string Card::toString()
{
    string str; 

    switch (value)
    {   
        case 1: str = "Ace of ";    
            break;
        case 2: str = "Two of ";    
            break;
        case 3: str = "Three of ";  
            break;
        case 4: str = "Four of ";   
            break;
        case 5: str = "Five of ";   
            break;
        case 6: str = "Six of ";    
            break;
        case 7: str = "Seven of ";  
            break;
        case 8: str = "Eight of ";  
            break;
        case 9: str = "Nine of ";   
            break;
        case 10: str = "Ten of ";   
                 break;
        case 11: str = "Jack of ";  
            break;
        case 12: str = "Queen of ";
            break;
        case 13: str = "King of ";  
            break;
        default: cerr << "Invalid Card value";
    }//switch

    switch (suit) 
    {   
        case SPADES: str += "Spades";   
            break;
        case HEARTS: str += "Hearts";
            break;
        case DIAMONDS: str += "Diamonds"; 
            break;
        case CLUBS: str += "Clubs"; 
            break;
        default: cerr << "Invalid Card suit";
    }//switch

    return str; 
}

const int Card::compareCard(const Card c) 
{
     int result;

     if (value == c.value)
     {
         result = 0;
     }
     else if (value == 1)
     {
         result = 1;
     }
     else if (c.value == 1)
     {
         result = -1;
     }
     else if (value < c.value)
     {
         result = 1;
     }
     else
     {
         result = -1;
     }

     return result;
}//compareCard
```

My Deck header file:

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H
#include "Card.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Deck
{
public:
    Deck();
    Deck(int num);

    void addCard(Card c);
    Card getTopCard();
    Card peekTopCard();

    int getNumCards();
    bool isEmpty();

    void shuffleDeck(int list[], int size);
    void cutDeck();

private:
    static const int MAX = 52;
    static const int NUM_SUITS = 4;
    static const int NUM_VALUES = 13;
    int numCards;
    Card myCard[MAX];

};
#endif
```

My Deck implementation file:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

Deck::Deck()
{
    char suits[4] = {Card::SPADES, Card::HEARTS, Card::DIAMONDS,   Card::CLUBS};
    int count = 0;  

    for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) 
    {
        for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
        {
            myCard[count] = Card(v, suits[s]); 
            count++;
        }           
    }//for
    int numCards = 0;
}//Deck

Deck::Deck(int num)
{
    char suits[4] = {Card::SPADES, Card::HEARTS, Card::DIAMONDS, Card::CLUBS};
    int count = 0;

    for (int s = 0; s < NUM_SUITS; s++) 
    {
        for (int v = 1; v <= NUM_VALUES; v++)
        {
            myCard[count] = Card(v, suits[s]);
            count++;
        }           
    }//for

    if ((num < 0) || (num > MAX))
    {
        cerr << "Invalid number of cards in the deck";
    }
    numCards = num;
}//Deck



void Deck::addCard(Card c)
{   
    if(numCards == MAX)
    {
        cerr << "Attempt to add to full deck";
    }//if
    else
    {
        myCard[numCards] = c;
        numCards++;
    }//else
}//addCard

Card Deck::getTopCard()
{
    Card c;

    if (numCards > 0) 
    {   
        c = myCard[0];  
        for (int i = 1; i < numCards; i++) 
        {
            myCard[i - 1] = myCard[i];
        }
    numCards--; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        cerr<<"Cannot add card from an empty deck.";
    }
    return c;   
}//getTopCard

Card Deck::peekTopCard()
{
    Card c;     

    if (numCards > 0)
    {   
        c = myCard[0];
    } 
    else 
    {
        cerr<<"Cannot add card from an empty deck.";
    }
    return c;
}//peekTopCard

int Deck::getNumCards()
{
    return numCards;
}//getNumCards

bool Deck::isEmpty()
{
    bool empty = true;
    if (numCards == 0)
    {
        empty = true;
    }
    else
    {
        empty = false;
    }

    return empty;
}//isEmpty

void Deck:: shuffleDeck(int list[], int size)
{
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int index = rand() % MAX;
        int temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[index];
        list[index] = temp;
    }//for
}//shuffleDeck
```

Comment: For some reason the indentation didn't post right.  Sorry about that.

Comment: You're putting in a lot of machinery with no purpose in mind. It's better to have a clear idea of what you want a class or function to do, before you start implementing it. What do you want the `compareCard` function to do? Once you have a clear statement of that, coding up the function is easy.

Comment: And parameters for shuffleDeck should be int list[], int size.  I left the function prototype as Deck &d.

Comment: @Beta, the compareCard function compares the value of the two cards and will return integer values such that: negative indicates the calling ovject is less than the parameter, zero indicates the two cards have equal value(suit is ignored by compareCard), and positive indicates the calling object is greater than the parameter.

Comment: Personally, one of my favorite parts of C++ is the ability to override operators. I think that `cardA < cardB` is much more readable than `cardA.compareCard(cardB) < 0`. So I would start by overloading <, >, and = operators.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  My code isn't even close to compiling though, that's what I am having problems with.  I have errors all over the place...

Comment: Rather than using `compareCard` function, I suggest overloading the comparison operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're starting a new codebase, start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, get every addition working perfectly before you introduce the next, and **never add to code that doesn't work**.

Let's start with `Card`:

```
// Card.h
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
class Card
{
 public:
  Card();

 private:
  int value;
 };
#endif


//Card.cc

#include "Card.h"
```

This compiles. Now we add a non-default constructor, a "getter" for the value, **and write a test:**

```
// in Card.h:

Card(int v);
int getValue();

// in Card.cc:

Card::Card(int v)
{
  value=v;
}

int Card::getValue()
{
  return(v);
}

// in testCard.cc:

#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Card X(5);

  cout << "card is " << X.getValue() << endl;

  return(0);
}
```

This doesn't compile; it has a bug. **Find the bug and fix it before you add anything more.**

Feel free to ask for help if you run into a problem you can't crack. By the time you get to things like `cut` and `shuffle`, you'll have solved a lot of small problems with ease.

**EDIT:**

You declare a default constructor (`Card()`) in `Card.h`, but you don't define it in `Car.cc`. There are places where `Deck` tries to construct a card without arguments (e.g. `Card c;`), and the linker has nothing to plug in there. Add a default constructor to `Card.cc`.

**EDIT:**

And your `shuffleDeck` looks like a work in progress. If you're having trouble, I suggest you try implementing `swapCards(int, int)` first.

**EDIT:**

The code you've posted is of two classes. Is there a main routine that uses them? You can't build an executable without a `main()` in there someplace (library yes, executable no).

**EDIT:**

You should be able to build the object files (`Card.o` and `Deck.o`) with what you have. I'd advise you to write (and build, and run) a test routine, something like:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Deck D;
  D.addCard(Card(10,'D'));
  D.addCard(Card(4,'C'));
  cout << D.getNumCards() << endl;

  D.cutDeck();

  while(!D.isEmpty())
    {
      Card C = D.getTopCard();
      cout << C.toString() << endl;
    }

  return(0);
}
```

*You should have been doing this all along, to test your functions as you added them.*

Comment: If I had time, I would just erase it all and start over.  But I don't have time, seeing as the assignment is due tomorrow night by 11:59.  I am just not grasping the concepts needed to write this.  This is only my second programming course and I think he is asking a bit much for the level we are all at.

Comment: Trust me, this is the fastest way. Put what you've written (`Card.h`, `Card.cc`, `Deck.h`, `Deck.cc`) into a directory for safe keeping, and try my way. Do you see the bug? It's a bug that appears in your code, so you've got to tackle it, and this is the easiest way.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? The compiler can be a big help in spotting bugs.

Comment: @mkjo0617, a decent compiler will tell you that `v` was not declared in the scope of `getValue()`. The line should be `return(value);`, and there are scope errors of this kind in your code. Once this is working, think about the next thing you want `Card` to have (suits? `compare()`? a decent output function?), implement and test, repeat.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try it today.  I eventually gave up last night because I had a nervous breakdown over it.

Comment: @mkjo0617: The more anxious you get, the harder it is to solve the problem. Cliché , but true. I'll be checking in all day. Leave comments here, and I'll edit my answer (this comment section is getting long).

Comment: I got it pretty much working. I worked with a couple of my classmates. How do I send you my code that I have done now? I only have two errors: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function__tmainCRTStartup and LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.

Comment: @mkjo0617, at the bottom of your question there is an "edit" button. Also, it looks as if you are having a problem linking object files together, so how are you compiling/building?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 to compile...I am not sure whether that answers your question.

Comment: Okay I edited my code.  If you can figure it out, I would be so excited :)

Comment: Okay that makes sense!  And yes my shuffle is a work in progress...I plan on using an FSM instead of what I am using now.

Comment: I added a default constructor to my Card implementation...but I still have one linking error.  Do you know where the other one might be?

Comment: No.  I don't have a main file that utilizes the classes yet.  All that's due tonight are the two header files and the two implementation files.  So the code will compile if I make a test main?

Comment: It probably would have been a lot easier had I tested everything as I went along.  As I stated before, I am a very novice programmer and my professor did not teach us to do this.  Now I know.  Thank you for the life lesson.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest augmenting your class by overloading the comparison operators:

```
class Card
{
  public:
    bool operator==(const Card& other) const
    {
         return ((value == other.value) && (suite == other.suite));
    }

    bool operator< (const Card& other) const
    {
         bool is_less_than = false;
         if (suite == other.suite)
         {
             is_less_than = value < other.value;
         }
         return is_less_than;
    }
    bool operator!= (const Card& other) const
    { return !(*this == other); }
    bool operator<= (const Card& other) const
    { return (*this == other) || (*this < other); }
    bool operator>  (const Card& other) const
    { return !(*this <= other); }
    bool operator>= (const Card& other) const
    { return !(*this < other); }
};
```

With the above overloaded operators, you can use other algorithms easier, such as std::sort, or std::find.

Comment: Your comparison isn't logical. Two cards of different suits will always be considered "less" than each other by your implementation.

Comment: @Mosterd: The comparison depends on the User's definition.  In the case of my answer, the ordering depends on the suit first, then the face value.  This will ensure that all cards of a suit are ordered together.  You may have a different interpretation of "less than" and you can write your own comparison method that is different.